# apply RewriteRule only if string exists in url

Tags: .htaccess

I have Urls which will always have `http://www.example.com/global/` but after `/global/` there may be name of a `city` or `franchise` in city or some other page

Examples are
`http://www.example.com/global/name-of-city`
or
`http://www.example.com/global/frnachise-then-name-of-city`

Now I have written some rules for both of the conditions & they are working

This is what I'm doing for urls like `http://www.example.com/global/name-of-city`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ products.php?city=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And here is what I'm doing for `franchise` including urls

```
RewriteRule ^franchise-management-.([\w-]+)/?$ franchise.php?city=$1 [L,QSA]
```

but the issue is the 2nd one works only if the 1st RewriteRule is commented otherwise 1st will be applied always

I need to put some condition with a check if url includes `franchise` then execute `RewriteRule for franchise` only otherwise execute the 1st RewriteRule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]   
RewriteRule ^franchise-management/([\w-]+)/?$ franchise-management.php?city=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ products.php?city=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Not working after replacing `-.` with `/`
can you please explain what `RewriteRule ^ - [L] ` supposed to do ?

Comment: using my old code just moving the rule `RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ products.php?city=$1 [L,QSA]` to last did the trick

Comment: Also please add some description for why you changed these lines `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f ` 
Thanks

Comment: @Ahmed 
    `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]` is an important rule in mod-rewrite, it avoids infinite loop error and skips the all rules bellow if a an existent file or dir is requested . by the way I had tested the code on my apache before posting here , it worked fine.